# Access violation while using fscanf_s

Tags: c, scanf

I want to read a file in a specific format, so I use fscanf_s and a while loop. But as soon as fscanf_s is processed, the program crashes with an access violation (0xC0000005).

Here's the code:

```
FILE *fp;
errno_t err = fopen_s(&fp, "C:\\data.txt", "r");

if (err != 0)
    return 0;

int minSpeed = 0;
int maxSpeed = 0;
char axis = '@';

while(!feof(fp)) 
{
    int result = fscanf_s(fp, "%c;%d-%d\n", &axis, &minSpeed, &maxSpeed);

    if (result != 3)
        continue;
}

fclose(fp);
```

The content of the file is line based, for example:

```
-;10000-20000
X;500-1000
S;2000-2400
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: What? no `feof_s()` or `fclose_s()`? Really, the `*_s` functions are worse than the plainly named functions: they require the same checks and make you feel safe when you aren't. I suggest you don't use them because of false sense of security and the fact they are not available on many implementations making your programs work only in a limited subset of possible machines.

Comment: @pmg I'm not using feof_s & fclose_s because they are not defined. But removing that _s from fscanf_s did the trick. It's working now! :-) Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I got the same problem when I tried a little test program.  Weird little functions, they are!

Comment: the `feof_s()` and `fclose_s()` were a joke (lol); apparently, the [correct fscanf_s() invocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ybhk9kc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)  would be `fscanf_s(fp, "%c;%d-%d\n", &axis, 1, &minSpeed, &maxSpeed);` with the extra `1` for the size of the `axis` "array". **Do not use the `*_s` functions!**

Comment: @pmg: you should put that as an answer :)

Answer (score 9):

Apparently, [`fscanf_s()` needs a size parameter after the address of the variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ybhk9kc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
fscanf_s(fp, "%c;%d-%d\n", &axis, 1, &minSpeed, &maxSpeed);
/* extra 1 for the size of the   ^^^ axis array */
```

But I suggest you do not use the `*_s` functions: they are worse than the plainly named functions --- they require the same checks and make you feel safe when you aren't. I suggest you don't use them because of false sense of security and the fact they are not available on many implementations making your programs work only in a limited subset of possible machines.

Use plain fscanf()

```
fscanf(fp, "%c;%d-%d\n", &axis, &minSpeed, &maxSpeed);
/* fscanf(fp, "%1c;%d-%d\n", &axis, &minSpeed, &maxSpeed); */
/* default 1   ^^^    same as for fscanf_s                 */
```

---

And your use of `feof()` is wrong.
The `fscanf()` returns EOF when there is an error (end-of-file or matching failure or read error ...).

You can use `feof()` to determine why `fscanf()` failed, not to check whether it would fail on the next time it is called.

```
/* pseudo-code */
while (1) {
    chk = fscanf();
    if (chk == EOF) break;
    if (chk < NUMBER_OF_EXPECTED_CONVERSIONS) {
        /* ... conversion failures */
    } else {
        /* ... all ok */
    }
}
if (feof()) /* failed because end-of-file reached */;
if (ferror()) /* failed because of stream error */;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you believe the file (data.txt) exists, your application is probably not running with a current directory set to where the file is. This would cause fopen_s() to fail.

Comment: Right, but fopen_s succeeds, I checked it in the visual studio debugger.