# Preventing buffer overflow when using fscanf

Tags: c++, input, buffer-overflow, scanf

I'm using fscanf to read some values from a CSV file and I want to ensure that the data read into the values will not be too large and cause a buffer overflow.

My csv file has the format int,string,string and my code to read is below (I will fix the while condition later):

```
while(fscanf(f, "%d,%[^,],%[^,]", &inArray[i].ID, inArray[i].label, inArray[i].brand)/*insert while condition here*/
```

When using scanf I would specify the length like so to prevent overflow: `scanf("%20f", example);`

But if I try the same with the above:     `while(fscanf(f, "%d,%20[^,],%10[^,]", &inArray[i].ID, inArray[i].label, inArray[i].brand)/*insert while condition here*/`

I get a crash when the code executes.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Is it crashing in the first iteration of your loop? How do you initialize `i`?

Comment: If you want to learn the C++ way of reading formatted input, you probably want to have a look at [cppreference on istream operator >>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `fscanf_s`, this function has security enhancements.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ybhk9kc(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Apparently, fscanf_s looks like a poor solution. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6153517/23118

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with fprintf when reading characters.

I would read the whole line first, e.g., with `getline()`, locate the separators (or tokenize the line), and then parse the individual elements.

Btw., the reason for you crash might also be a wrong definition/initialization of `inArray`.

Answer (score 2):

OP likely used the wrong width in the `fscanf()`.

Although OP did not post details about `inArray[i]` let's assume it was

```
struct {
  int ID;
  char label[20];
  char brand[10];
} inArray[100];
```

The format should then be

```
"%d,%19[^,],%9[^,]"
```

The width of 19 needs to be 1 less than the size of the destination, thus allowing a spot for the '\0'.